# OSB Editor in JDeveloper 12C and ORACLE SOA SUITE 12C

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, osb, soa-suite

Hello I have a question about OracleSOASuite12C and JDEVELOPER 12C.
I have a Server with ORACLE SOA SUITE 12C and I have my computer with JDeveloper 12C.
I want to create an OSB Project in JDeveloper, but I don't have this option, probably I need to connect my Server with JDeveloper or I have to connect to install SOASuite in my PC. 
I want to create an OSB Project to edit my OSB Server.

Coul i do?

Comment: Please add more context to your question. What does " but I don't have this option " mean? Add code samples, with the problem as well as possible solutions you are trying.
Writing code is not like talking to the stars.

Answer (score 2):

You MUST use the SOA quickstart installer to install the Jdeveloper version that has support fo SOA and OSB. you can find it [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/downloads/index.html).
11g allowed you to download the extensions to JDeveloper. In 12c+ they are included in the QS install.

Answer (score 1):

Is this JDeveloper installed yourself or the one included in the SOA suite? During installation of the SOA suite you either have to link to your JDeveloper or let it install the one included. The included one is location in your ORACLE_HOME. Jdeveloper does not have SOA compatibility out of the box